# How to access nested element of mongo query result using Java and R?

Tags: java, r, mongodb

I am using Java and R to fetch data from my database and implement prediction. My `json` in mongodb is like:

```
{
 "Server" : [
    {
        "deviceName" : "NEWSCVMM",
        "availability" : 100,
        "osVersion" : "6.3.9600",
        "averageResponseTime" : 0.422,
        "useswapmemory" : "983040",
        "freeswapmemory" : "983040",
        "model" : "Virtual Machine",
        "numberOfCpu" : "1",
        "vendor" : "Microsoft Corporation",
        "vmList" : [ ],
        "macadd" : [ ],
        "cpuInfo" : "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5670  @ 2.93GHz",
        "memory" : "6188596",
        "serialNo" : "00252-00000-00000-AA228",
        "cpuUtilization" : 0,
 }]

}
```

I want to access `cpuUtilization` from that json. I tried to access nested values using (.) but get result as NULL. I also tried to execute same on R shell but get result as NULL.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
c.eval("query <- dbGetQuery(db,'   mycollection','{\"hostId\":\"0.0.0.0\",\"windowsServer.cpuUtilization\":{\"$ne\":\"null\"},\"runtimeMillis\":{\"$ne\":\"null\"}}')");
 c.eval("date <- query$runtimeMillis");
 c.eval("host_id <- query$hostId");
 c.eval("cpu <- query$Server.cpuUtilization");

 c.eval("all_data<-data.frame(cpu,date)");
 c.eval("training<- all_data");
 c.eval("rf_fit<-randomForest(cpu~date,data=training,ntree=500)");
 c.eval("new <- data.frame(date="+my_predicted_date+ ")");
 c.eval("predictions<-predict(rf_fit,newdata=new)");
 REXP memory_predictions= c.eval("predictions");
```

How do I access nested elements on either R shell or using java?

Answer (score 0):

Dot notation should work in Java, I have been using it for quite a while now.
Check your code carefully, there might be a slight mistake somewhere.

Can you please post a part of your code here? I can then take a look and comment.

Here is what I normally do - 
Lets say my document is like this -

```
{_id:0, start : {x:10, y:50}, end : {x:20, y:100}}
{_id:1, start : {x:20, y:50}, end : {x:30, y:100}}
{_id:2, start : {x:30, y:50}, end : {x:40, y:100}}
```

If I want to query based on "x" value in start field, I would write something like this:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
DB db = client.getDB("YourDBNAME");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("YOURCOLLECTIONAME");
QueryBuilder builder =  QueryBuilder().start("start.x").greaterThan("20");
DBCursor cur = collection.find(builder.get());

while(cursor.hasNext())
{
 System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

Compare this code snippet with yours and see. You should get it working fine. 
Let me know if this helps or you need more help on this.